# Is it theoretically possible to specialise trait behaviour?

Tags: rust, traits

Consider the following scenario:

- I want to implement a trait `Do` on all the types that implement a trait `CanDo`.
- Out of the types that `CanDo`, some implement a trait `CanDoQuickly`.
- I would like `Do` to be implemented in one way for those types that `CanDo`, but not `CanDoQuickly`, and in another way for those types that `CanDoQuickly`.

I know that, in Rust, we have no negative trait bounds. My intuition is that we should probably be able to use opt-in built-in to achieve this (although, I did try unsuccessfully).

I am wondering if it is at all possible, no matter the complexity of the code, to achieve what I would like to do on stable Rust. If not, is it a design choice? Is it inherently bad to want to do something like this? It sounds like such a common problem to me that I'd be very surprised to find out it's a deprecated practice.

Comment: Probably dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898130/trait-specialization

Comment: That question seems to address the question "why doesn't it work?", but not the question "is it possible to do such a thing?".

Answer (score 2):

It is possible on `nightly` with the still unstable `specialization` feature and a `default` implementation (see also [the tracking issue for specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844)):

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait DoIt {
    fn do_it(&self);
}

impl<T> DoIt for T
where
    T: CanDo,
{
    default fn do_it(&self) {
        self.do_impl()
    }
}

impl<T> DoIt for T
where
    T: CanDoQuickly,
{
    fn do_it(&self) {
        self.do_quickly_impl()
    }
}

trait CanDo {
    fn do_impl(&self) {
        println!("slowly");
    }
}

trait CanDoQuickly: CanDo {
    fn do_quickly_impl(&self) {
        println!("quickly");
    }
}

struct S1;
impl CanDo for S1 {}
impl CanDoQuickly for S1 {}

struct S2;
impl CanDo for S2 {}

fn main() {
    S1.do_it();
    S2.do_it();
}
```

Comment: I see. Interesting! Is there an estimate on how long it could take for `specialization` to make it into stable Rust? Does your answer imply that it is impossible to do the same thing in stable Rust?

Comment: As for the timeline, that is what the tracking issue is for. It's more than three years old and the remaining issues don't look easy, so I wouldn't hold my breath.